# Parse String to BigDecimal in several Locales

Tags: java, string, parsing, locale, bigdecimal

I have to parse a String, which represents a number, into a BigDecimal.
My problem is that my users could produce these numbers in several locales,
and I cannot know beforehand which locale I'm parsing.
For instance, I could get:

- 1234
- 1.234
- 1234.56
- 1234,56
- 1.234,56
- 1'234.56

These are always currencies, so the decimal part is always 0-to-2 number.
Is there a safe way to parse these numbers?
In particular, I fear that's pretty dangerous to tell between (for instance) 1.200 (a thousand and two hundred) from 1.20 (one and twenty cents).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can force your String to represent a double correctly, then parse it

```
    public static String getCurrency(String val) {

    // if val doesn't have decimal part ex 1234 or 1.234 (I suppose only 2 decimal values are allowed, usually the case with currencies
    if( val.charAt(val.length()-3) != '.' && val.charAt(val.length()-3) != ',' ) {
        val = val + ".00";
    }
    // get rid of . , ' ...
    val = val.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    // add the point to mark the decimal part
    val = val.substring(0, val.length()-2) + "." + val.substring(val.length()-2);
    return val;
}
```

testing it :

```
    String str1 = "1.234,56";
    String str2 = "1'234.56";
    String str3 = "1234.56";
    String str4 = "1.234";
    String str5 = "1234";
    String str6 = "1234,56";

    System.out.println (getCurrency(str1));
    System.out.println (getCurrency(str2));
    System.out.println (getCurrency(str3));
    System.out.println (getCurrency(str4));
    System.out.println (getCurrency(str5));
    System.out.println (getCurrency(str6));
```

which prints :

```
    1234.56
    1234.56
    1234.56
    1234.00
    1234.00
    1234.56
```

Comment: Thanks. Assuming there are never more than 2 decimal digits, this could be a good solution. I'd like a stronger one, tough. For instance, a person could easily tell that 1'212'456.230 should not be parsed into "1212456230,00".
I think that, if two kind of separators are found, then the second one is for decimals. Otherwise, if separator is found more than once, is for thousands.

Comment: Moreover, I meant that a number could have also only one decimal. With a little fix, this, could works. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm afraid checking for 2 separators or repeated separator won't always work either, for instance 1.200 (a thousand and two hundred) will be considered 1.20 (one and twenty cents).

Comment: For 1.200 there are neither repeated separators, nor 2 separators. My check should be safe enough, provided there are at least 2 separators. In case of only one separator, you solution could be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "-1.234,5";
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(
        str.replaceAll("([^0-9-][0-9]{0,2})$|[^0-9-]", "$1")
                .replaceAll("[^0-9-]", "."));
System.out.println(number); // Will print "-1234.5"
```

Comment: I fear this won't work for (for instance) "-1.234". That will returns "-12.34", instead of wanted "-1234,00".

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought there are always 2 decimals, will fix answer.